# how to get User Email Id in Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is it possible to get user default email account directly from an app?
 How ?
Any idea how to get email

Comment: No this is not possible, you will have to ask the user to provide it.

Comment: Since it is not possible, due to privacy protection the answer is correct.